# how to modify where clause in asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i configure Select with Where How should i write it on my VB side to get the conditional data

example

```
select * from student where username = @username and password= @password
```

how do i write the value of @username and @password on vb coding side

Comment: [How to: Create and Execute an SQL Statement that Returns Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using commands and sqlParemters...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: i been doing that all the while, but i need to use sqlDataSource built in function, therefore i really need know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("Username").DefaultValue = myUsername
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("Password").DefaultValue = myPassword
SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
```

Was this what you are asking? Please, clarify.